# Multiple CustomSort equivalent to Multiple SortDescription

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListCollectionView get from ViewModel in View:

`var collectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ViewModel.Items);`

And group&sort by certain columns:

```
// group
collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Index"));
// sort
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Index", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Key", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

It works as expected (First group sorted by Index, and sub items sorted by Key alphabetically.

For now I want to use custom "Key" sort with the implementation of IComparer, and I've tried use SortDescription with CustomSort, but CustomSort does clear SortDescription if used. So only the CustomSort takes effect.

```
collectionView.CustomSort = new CustomItemKeyComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
collectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Index", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

So how to use CustomSort with multiple column sort in ListCollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Your `CustomItemKeyComparer` class should contain logic to sort the items by *all* properties.
2. Add another property to your data item class that returns a value based on the custom sorting logic and then simply add another `SortDescription` to the collection view.

In other words, you shouldn't mix `SortDescriptions` and `CustomSort`. It's one or the other but not both.

Comment: I'd prefer option one. Is there an example on how to "sort the items by all properties" by your mean?

Comment: @imckl: It depends on your custom sorting logic. So if both `Index` and `Key` are equal, only then you should compare according to the logic that you currently have in `CustomItemKeyComparer`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the answer given by @mm8 and the first option provided.

I will be rewriting some code from this blog in order to make a custom IComparer that supports multiple columns/properties: https://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/wpf-listcollectionview-for-sorting-filtering-and-grouping

```
public class SortCreaturesByAgeAndFirstName : IComparer
{
    public int Compare( object x, object y )
    {
        if( x as CreatureModel == null && y as CreatureModel == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( "SortCreatures can 
                                    only sort CreatureModel objects." );
        }
        if( ((CreatureModel) x).Age > ((CreatureModel) y).Age )
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if( ((CreatureModel) x).Age < ((CreatureModel) y).Age )
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            // If the Age of the creatures are equal then sort by another property
            return string.Compare(x.FirstName, y.FirstName);
        }
    }
}
```